# Craft URLs intermittently being cached as /index.php/my-page/ or /index.php?p=my-page

Tags: url, cache

Cross-posting from [here](https://github.com/themccallister/craft.cache-clear/issues/2), as I'm not sure if this is a Craft issue or specific to the `cache-clear` plugin.

Intermittently (twice in a day now), I've seen templates being cached with Craft URLs outputting as either `/index.php/my-page/` or `/index.php?p=my-page`

Once this happens, clearing cache via the plugin url (http://domain.com/actions/cacheClear/clear?key=myKey) doesn't seem to fix anything, but clearing cache in the control panel does.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an explanation of why this can occur on the Craft help section here: http://buildwithcraft.com/help/why-index.php

Comment: Grah! I knew I saw something about that somewhere. Thanks.

Comment: Based on the comments in `/craft/app/etc/config/defaults/general.php`, it looks like I don't _also_ have to set `usePathInfo` if I set `'omitScriptNameInUrls' => true`

Wonderful!

Comment: I've added that in my general.php, yet index.php?p=my-page remains. Its only on production, not dev or local. Any ideas? example.com/my-page works on all environments.

Comment: update: I am using a 'maintenance mode' that blocks access based on IP address on production. That has a setting in the index.php file and if on uses another file to check access by IP. That process may affect removing index.php. I disabled that, cleared Craft caches, and URLs no longer have index.php.